# Reduce size between bar graphs in R

Tags: r, plot

I looked up many other questions and answers but still haven't been able to figure this out. I have the following code and data to create bar graphs and I'd like to reduce the space between the 4 bars. I know I can increase the bar size but that takes up unnecessary space. I've used position = position_dodge(width = ) but that doesn't seem to work for this graph. Sorry I imagine the answer is really simple so any help would be much appreciated :).

```
ggplot(freq_intensity, aes(x= reorder (category, -frequency), y=frequency))+
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width=10)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, fun.args = list(mult=1), geom = "errorbar", width=0.2, size=0.9) +
  geom_jitter(colour="limegreen",shape=16,size=2, position=position_jitter(0.1))+
  ggtitle("") +
  xlab("Categories") + ylab("Mean responses") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) +  
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_line())
```

```
structure(list(video_number = 1:40, category = c("neutral", 
"neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", 
"neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "pleasant", "pleasant", "pleasant", 
"pleasant", "pleasant", "pleasant", "pleasant", "pleasant", "pleasant", 
"pleasant", "unpleasant", "unpleasant", "unpleasant", "unpleasant", 
"unpleasant", "unpleasant", "unpleasant", "unpleasant", "unpleasant", 
"unpleasant", "painful", "painful", "painful", "painful", "painful", 
"painful", "painful", "painful", "painful", "painful"), frequency = c(55, 
56, 90, 104, 47, 38, 48, 52, 43, 38, 162, 139, 137, 131, 143, 
177, 151, 117, 164, 82, 116, 75, 105, 67, 75, 61, 133, 109, 123, 
150, 196, 191, 182, 141, 151, 148, 181, 77, 134, 128), intensity = c(2.8, 
2.7, 3.2, 3.2, 3.5, 2.6, 3.2, 2.9, 3.4, 2.8, 3.6, 3.6, 3.7, 3.5, 
3.7, 3.9, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.4, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.7, 3.3, 3.6, 4.4, 
3.7, 3.8, 4.2, 5, 4.8, 4.4, 4, 4.1, 3.9, 4.8, 3.7, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a wider bar width, and then to save the output with a narrower aspect ratio? That's how I understand "I can increase the bar size but that takes up unnecessary space."

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jon. I've added {r, fig.width = 3, fig.asp = 0.9} at the top but that doesn't reduce the size between the bars. It just makes the figure more into a square by stretching it out vertically. I could increase the bar width to reduce the white space, but I'd rather just reduce the white space without changing the bar width. :)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to control the white space directly, rather you can control the proportion of the space that is taken up by the bars, and the total space, and thereby indirectly control the white space.

Comment: Yes I've seen other people giving that as a solution so I guess I must be doing it wrong. When I add fig.asp at the top it doesn't actually reduce the white space, that remains the size of one bar graph. Is there another way to create a narrower aspect ratio instead of adding fig.asp = 0.9 at the top?

Comment: If you increase the width of bars the space between them reduces automatically `+.... stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", width = 0.8, position = position_dodge(width=10)) + ...` Is that what you want?